# Visual Studio 2022 feature for showing tooltips on mouse over

Tags: intellisense, visual-studio-2022

What option or feature must I enable in Visual Studio 2022 to get tooltips to show when hovering the mouse over a method, object, or error (i.e. red squiggly)? See screenshot comparing VS 2019 and 2022. I've searched for variations on VS 2022 and intellisense, intellicode, and it's not clear what changed with VS 2022.

[Screenshot of VS 2019 vs. 2022 tooltip compare on mouse-over](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hfzQ6.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

The answer: this feature is "Quick Info". It can be accessed by mousing over, the menu option Edit > Intellisense > Quick Info, or the key combo Ctrl-K, Ctrl-I.

HOWEVER - I'm running VS 2019 and 2022 in virtual machine on an M1 Mac using parallels. I suspect that there is an issue with parallels which is preventing 2022 from showing Quick Info - even though VS 2019 Quick Info works fine.

What's odd is that some mouse hovers do work in VS 2022 on the VM. E.g. "references" links that VS injects in the UI to show where the method is referenced, or what user last checked in the code. I'll pursue this over on the parallels forums.

Comment: Hi, glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider adding an answer and changing its status to Answered. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :) It will also help others to solve the similar issue.

Comment: There was also an intellisense issue in Visual Studio 2022 that has been resolved - at least it is in 17.4.0.

Comment: Jingmiao Xu-MSFT - Ctrl+K, Ctrl+I DOES NOT solve problem 'Visual Studio 2022 feature for showing tooltips on mouse over'.Now in VS 17.7.4 is stil this problem as many other long time non solved problems. VS was never as buggy as now. Of course, VS Feedback does not work at all.

Comment: Just updated to 17.8.3 and its not working.

Comment: Mouse hover quick info still not working for me in 17.8.5. Hasn't been working since first VS2022 release. I suspected Resharper from interfering, but disabling it doesn't help. Using CTRL-K-I or Edit->Intelli->QuickInfo doesn't work either.

Comment: @RatzMouze Try disabling extensions as pointed out in my answer. Would be interesting to see if that is your issue as well.

Comment: @Rev I Reinstalled my visual studio and then it worked again, but maybe it was my problem too. I did have some "homemade" extensions installed, that i haven't reinstalled after reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

As I already pointed out in the comments, the "Quick Info" popup hasn't been working for me since first VS2022 release. It wasn't showing on mouse hover, or using CTRL-K-I or selecting Edit->Intellisense->QuickInfo.

When I started disabling some VS extensions I noticed, that the extension "Porting Assistant for .NET 2022" was almost constantly doing some background processing as indicated by the icon in the lower left corner of VS. After I disabled it and restarted VS, the issue was fixed.

Maybe the problem is not related to this specific extension, but to some extensions performing background tasks which may interfere with the quick info.

Answer (score -2):

Press in your terminal <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>f</kbd> search `settings.json` and writing:

```json
"terminal.integrated.enableMultiLinePasteWarning": false
```

Comment: This seems to be about Visual Studio Code, but the question is about the real Visual Studio (2022 here).